# How to shelve a pending changes from workspace using Java SDK?

Tags: java, tfs, tfs-sdk, shelve

I have a code written using TFS SDK for Java to check-in pending changes from workspace to TFS, however we need to change it, so that files are not directly checked-in, rather they are shelved on the shelveset.

Does any one know how I can do that properly using Java SDK? Or any reference to help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [the code for the CLC (cross platform command line code) which implements the Shelve functionality](https://github.com/Microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/blob/master/source/com.microsoft.tfs.client.clc/src/com/microsoft/tfs/client/clc/vc/commands/CommandShelve.java#L103). Basically it comes down to retrieving the `workspace` and the calling `.shelve`.